# improving a word combination script

Tags: python

Any way to make this better or more simple? I know it generates a whole lot of words and when you try to combine more than 4 lines on one sentence it doesn't look the way it should.

```
infile = open('Wordlist.txt.txt','r')
wordlist = []
for line in infile:
    wordlist.append(line.strip())
infile.close()
outfile = open('output.txt','w')
for word1 in wordlist:
    for word2 in wordlist:
        out = '%s %s' %(word1,word2)
        #feel free to #comment one of these two lines to not output to file or screen
        print out
        outfile.write(out + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

Comment: For future reference, indent your code to make sure it doesn't end up as gobbledy-gook.  Someone else just put in an edit to correct the code indent, but check back to make sure it matches what you had before.

Comment: What are some examples of some bad/undesired output?

Comment: Because we do not know the contents of `Wordlist.txt.txt`, nor what you want the output to be, it is hard for us to help you. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
with open('Wordlist.txt.txt') as infile:
    words = [line.strip() for line in infile]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for word1, word2 in itertools.product(words, repeat=2):
        outfile.write("%s %s\n" %(word1, word2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If each line in your infile contains exactly 2 words you may consider:

```
from itertools import product

with open('Wordlist.txt.txt','r') as infile:
   wordlist=infile.readlines()

with open('output','w') as ofile:
   ofile.write('\n'.join(map(product, [line.strip().split() for line in wordlist])))
```